# View images without gui

Tags: terminal

What methods are available for people to use to view images on the command line? I tried the accepted answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/how-do-i-display-images-without-starting-x11) but i got the error `bash: fbi: command not found` so I'm not quite sure what the problem is. I also tried [this](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/09/how-to-display-images-on-raspbian-command-line/) (first duck-duck-go result) but it gave me this when trying to install:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install -y fim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fim
```

So how can i view images on the command line without the GUI?

This question has been marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/how-do-i-display-images-without-starting-x11) and i will admit that they are extremely similar however at the bottom of every question that has been closed as a duplicate (first result for `duplicate:yes` [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/access-the-raspberry-with-the-usb-cable-only)) it says:

> marked as duplicate by lenik, syb0rg, RPi Awesomeness, Impulss, Butters Mar 3 '14 at 20:12
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. **If     those answers do not fully address your
>    question, please ask a new question.**

I take that to mean if i see a question that is similar to my question but the answers *do not work* which is the case here i should ask a new one. therefore i do not believe that this should be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display images without starting X11?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/how-do-i-display-images-without-starting-x11)

Comment: @goobering i don't think it's a duplicate, please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use FBI, because FIM is no longer in the repository. You can install it with the command `apt-get install fbi`.

Comment: This seems to only work if you use <kbd> ctrl </kbd><kbd> alt </kbd><kbd> F-1 </kbd> and then the command. Can you use it in a 80 by 24 character terminal?

Answer (score 3):

gpicview is a fast and simple image viewer.try this, navigate to the working directory, then type the following command.

```
gpicview example.jpg
```

Comment: `gpicview` is *["A Simple and Fast Image Viewer](http://lxde.sourceforge.net/gpicview/)* **for X"** -- in fact it appears to be part of LXDE, the default Raspbian desktop.  But the OP is explicitly looking for something which works **outside of X** (i.e., on the [framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer)).